# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

Fiz uma requisição e no resultado trouxe $result. Mas eu queria acessar dentro da string como objeto e aparece esse erro. Vi uns erros parecidos em outras perguntas, mas pra mim não ficou claro.

```
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo var_dump($result);
echo "<br>";
echo json_decode($result);
```

> ```
> {"response":{"dsLOGIN":{"dsLOGIN":{}}}}
> string(39) "{"response":{"dsLOGIN":{"dsLOGIN":{}}}}"
> ```

Erro:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Comment: O que aparece se tu fizer um `print_r($result);`?

Comment: `{"response":{"dsLOGIN":{"dsLOGIN":{}}}}` -  A mesma linha do echo $result @ThiagoSantos

Comment: Em qual linha está dando o erro? Nessa: `echo json_decode($result);`?

Comment: Sim, nela mesmo. `echo json_decode($result); ` @ThiagoSantos

Comment: `json_decode($result);` retorna um Objeto PHP, e com um ECHO você tenta escrever esse Objeto como String, o que está causando esse erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OBJECT OF CLASS STDCLASS**

Ao utilizar `json_decode()` você tem como resultado um Objeto, ou um Array de Objetos ([Fonte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)) e, ao utilizar `ECHO` em um Objeto, causa a tentativa de conversão dele para String, ocasionando o Erro:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in

Para escrever um Objeto diretamente é preciso utilizar `print_r()` assim exibindo até mesmo suas propriedades ([Fonte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php)).

No seu caso deve funcionar apropriadamente o seguinte:

```
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo var_dump($result);
echo "<br>";
$jsonResult = json_decode($result);
print_r($jsonResult); // $jsonResult já é um Objeto
print_r($jsonResult->response) // $jsonResult->esponse também contém um Objeto
```

Comment: Agora, entendi. Eu estava só usando o `echo` e estava me confundindo. Obrigado!